# Packing of rectangles with given width and length

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, tree, packing

I have a tree with rectangles in the leaf nodes, and a 'V' or a 'H' in internal nodes. I want to pack the rectangles, given their width and height. If theres a 'V', I will pack the left and the right child, and if theres a 'H', i want to pack the left child on top of the right child. In the end I want to determine the coordinates of each rectangle. I have attached an image showing the tree and the constructed packing.

[image]

What I'm doing is, I am going through each node in the tree. When it reaches a leaf node, it builds a struct rectangle and stores it into an array. Then when it reaches a 'V', I simply change my x-coordinate of the last rectangle in the array by adding the width of the second last rectangle in the array. I construct a new rectangle, that that fits the entire set of last rectangles and put it in the array. If I get an 'H', I increment the y coordinate of the specific rectangles in the array. However, I am having trouble doing this, as I dont know which all rectangles y coordinate should be changes. There can be any number of such rectangles. PLEASEE HELP!!

Comment: Sorry but this is still quite unclear. Perhaps you could show the code you have so far - it might make things clearer? What does `9(4,5)` by a node mean?

Comment: What would happen if box 3 had only width 1 or even 0.5? I feel the description you have given doesn't guarantee a unique solution

Comment: This is BOXTRIS! The bottom level is supposed to disappear!

Comment: I suggest you describe your problem more precisely. The first paragraph of your question seems to be describing the requirement while the second paragraph seems to be describing your implementation and the problem you encountered with implementation. the requirement part is not precise. For example, if left child and right child both contain multiple rectangles, what is considered a valid "left pack to right"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Packing of rectangles given a tree](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22545385/packing-of-rectangles-given-a-tree)

Answer (score 0):

After much examination of your question I think I might have understood your problem.

your packing has a rule (which you did not state) that for left/right packing, rectangles need to be bottom aligned. For top/bottom packing, rectangles need to be left aligned. your coordinate system use the bottom left as (0,0)

I also assume that after packing complete you need to produce the coordinates of each rectangle (given that each rectangle's dimension is known data, for each rect you only need to produce 1 coordinate, e.g. coordinate of the bottom left corner)

using array to preserve such data might not work. your input packing relation is stored in a tree, and you can use exactly the same tree to store the packing result.

Every node in the tree will represent a rectangle. Internal node will represent a rectangle that "packs" child rectangles. For each node you need to define variable to store it's dimension, it's absolute coordinate, AND it's relative coordinate (relative to it's immediate parent).

You can then conduct two traversal through the tree, first traversal to calculate all the relative coordinates from bottom up (a depth first search), the second traversal to deduct absolute coordinate from top to bottom.

below are the pseudo code for the first traversal (in a recursive function for DFS)

```
packtree(treeroot)
{
    if(treeroot is a leaf) return; // do nothing and return the function

    packtree(leftchild);
    packtree(rightchild);
    if(treeroot is V type)
    {
      treeroot.width = leftchild.width+rightchild.width
      treeroot.height = leftchild.height > rightchild.height ? leftchild.height : rightchild.height
      leftchild.relative_cor = (0,0)
      rightchild.relative_cor = (leftchild.width, 0)
    }
    else if(treeroot is H type)
    { 
      treeroot.width = leftchild.width> rightchild.width ? leftchild.width:rightchild.width
      treeroot.height = leftchild.height + rightchild.height
      leftchild.relative_cor = (0, rightchild.height) // because he is sitting on top of the rightchild
      rightchild.relative_cor = (0,0)
    }
}
```

I will leave the second traversal to you. :)

Comment: Hey! thanks for the help. When you say i will need two traversal, what do you mean exactly? 
I understand that the first traversal will check if a node is V type or H type. 
It will increment the coordinates of the respective children, accordingly.
But how will this pack the rectangles as given in the figure? According to the tree in the figure, I will go to node 13 first, change the x-coordinate of only 5. And the coordinates of node 2 will still be (0,0). Then I will go to node 14, change the Y coordinate of node 13. That will not change the coordinates of node 2 and node 5.

Comment: Your interpretation is correct. In the first traversal you only update the RELATIVE coordinates, which is defined using the immediate parent rect's bottom left corner as (0,0).  I suggest walkthrough the first traversal manually and draw the tree with all node dimension and coord value calculated, you will be able to see the point. In fact at that point the tree is good enough for you to draw the packing diagram.

Comment: the second traversal is needed if you want to obtain the absolute coords of each rect. The logic is quite simple, if you know the absolute coord of a parent, given the two children's relative coord you can get their absolute coord as well, you can proceed as such downwards.

Answer (score 0):

I got it!

I used firemana's suggestion to not do it using array. However I did it in one traversal only. I went to each node of the tree. If it was a leaf node, i just did nothing. If it was an 'H' i went to the right first then to the left child. If it was a 'V', i went to the left first then to the right. If the node was a 'H', I changed the y-coordinate of all the left children to the height of the right child. And if it was a 'V', I updated the x-coordinate of the right children to the width of the left child.

The solution is pretty easy once we figure out the logic. Thanks people!